# How can I pipe an alias that requires sudo through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, sudo

I've set up so that I can SSH securely into my home PC from my laptop. Today, I tried running an update just to test, but I couldn't do it from the laptop.

What I basically wanted to do, was to pass the command to the machine without SSH-ing into it while not keeping the connection alive. I tried looking around online to see if I could find something, but nothing seems to work.

These are the commands I tried:

```bash
$ ssh myip 'sysupg &'
bash: sysupg: command not found
```

```bash
echo "mypassword" | ssh myip 'sudo -S dnf upgrade -y &'
[sudo] password for myuser:
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: a password is required
```

```bash
echo "mypassword" | ssh myip 'sudo -S -k dnf upgrade -y &'
[sudo] password for myuser:
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: a password is required
```

When it asks for my password (`[sudo] password for myuser:`), it doesn't let me enter anything, just proceeds, giving me the last two `sudo` errors.

**tldr:** pass a command that requires `sudo` through `ssh` to another machine, "automatically" close the connection as soon as the command is passed and, if possible, execute the command in x amount of minutes.

Comment: Try removing the "&" from the remote command, and run sudo with the "-b" option (run command in background) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible way:

```
ssh -t myip 'sudo -b dnf upgrade -y >/tmp/aa 2>&1'
```

- You want your task to run whilst disconnected; use the `1>` and `2>` redirections
- You want your task to run in background; use `sudo -b` option
- You want `ssh` to provide interactivity to `sudo`; use `ssh -t` option

Other possible but not recommended way:

```
echo PASSWORD | ssh myip 'sudo -S -b dnf upgrade -y >/tmp/aa 2>&1'
```

- You want `sudo` to read password on stdin; use `sudo -S` option instead of `ssh -t`
- Having cleartext password in command history is a fault

You missed the `sudo -b` option, because the `&` makes password prompt to run in background and not your only desired task.

Also, missing `1>` or `2>` redirections retains the ssh connection.

However, provided that you use `PubkeyAuthentication`, a safe way to do the trick is:

```
ssh root@myip 'dnf upgrade -y >/tmp/aa 2>&1 &'
```

- Set `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `sshd_conf`
- Copy your public key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Have always your private key passphrase protected, and use `ssh-agent`

But, the best way is to use `screen` at the server side:

```
ssh -t myip screen -RD
sudo -s
...whatever...
Ctrl-A d (detach and disconnect)
```

Later, reattach the session:

```
ssh -t myip screen -RD
```

- You meet your requirements
- You reattach your session alive
- You learn screen

Comment: Amazing! Very interesting read and everything worked. Thanks!